# Anything I put in path get's deleted after I close it

Tags: path, system-error

So, I've been looking for solution's on the web but I can't find any. Every time I try to add something to path it deletes it right after I close it. This is on my user. However if you do it as administrator it will save it. I can't use here because the admin is another profile and I all the developing tools are in my profile. Can any of you help me.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem like a programming question. I would try to ask on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/ as it seems off topic here.

Comment: ok thank for the advice.

Comment: Also, you can try to search up your question to make sure it hasn't been answered before ;)

Comment: yeah I tried looking for some solution's here and also on superuser.com but I couldn't find anything